# Element-wise multiplication between all the elements of a vector

Tags: python, numpy

What is the efficient way to do element wise mulitplication between all the elements of a numpy array.

If A is a vector of 100 elements then A2 is a vector of 100^2 elements.

Example

**Input :**

```
a = [5,2,3,4]
```

**output**

```
a2=[5*5,5*2,5*3,5*4,2*5,2*2,2*3,2*4,3*5,3*2,3*3,3*4,4*5,4*2,4*3,4*4]
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.outer(a,a).reshape(-1)

array([25, 10, 15, 20, 10,  4,  6,  8, 15,  6,  9, 12, 20,  8, 12, 16])
```

Use [numpy.outer](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.outer.html) - to compute the outer product of two vectors
 and then [numpy.reshape](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) - to get array into expected shape.